# Jquery mobile get listview chosen item and send it text to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

i make JQM application which have listwiew and i want to send the choosen item text to another page to use this text to get data from server by ajax

the first page

```
`<div data-role="page" id="hteacher" >
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<h1>Welcome teacher 1</h1>
 <div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#hteacher" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#t_addclass" data-icon="plus" data-rel="dialog">ADD Class</a></li>
    <li><a href="#msg_page" data-icon="star" data-rel="dialog">MSG</a></li>`<div data-      role="page" id="hteacher" >

       <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Welcome teacher 1</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar">
     <ul>
    <li><a href="#hteacher" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#t_addclass" data-icon="plus" data-rel="dialog">ADD Class</a></li>
    <li><a href="#msg_page" data-icon="star" data-rel="dialog">MSG</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div data-role="content">
   <p></p>
  <h2>list of classes </h2>
 <ul data-role="listview" id="classes_list" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true"   data-filter="true">
 <script>
$( document ).delegate("#hteacher", "pagecreate", function() {
 $.post("teacher_login.php", { teacher_user:teacher_user ,  get_classes:"1"} ,        function(data ,status){


  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
$.each(obj,function(){
 var str =this['class_un'];
 var  html =  ' <li><a href="#" ><img src="class1.jpg">'+ str + '</a></li>';
 $("#classes_list").append (html).listview("refresh");
          });
 });
$('#classes_list').on('click','li', function () {
 teacher_choose_class = $(this).text();
 $.mobile.changePage("#teacher_classes");
});  
 });                      
</script>
 </ul>
 </div>

 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<h1>Welcome To .....</h1>
 </div>
```

the second page that want to send the selected item text to it

```
<div data-role="page" id="teacher_classes" >
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<h1>Welcome to class A</h1>
   <div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#hteacher" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#attend" data-icon="check" data-rel="dialog">Take Attendance</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>

 <div data-role="content">
 <p></p>
<h2>class student </h2>
<ul data-role="listview"  id="student_list_class" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
 <script>
 $("#teacher_classes").live("pageshow",function(event){
   alert(teacher_choose_class);
  $.post("teacher_login.php", { class_un:teacher_choose_class ,  get_students:"1"} ,      function(data ,status){
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
$.each(obj,function(){
 var str =this['child_name'];
 var  html =  ' <li><a href="#put_grade"><img src="student1.jpg">'+ str + '</a></li>';
  $("#student_list_class").append (html).listview("refresh");
     });

 });                      
 });
</script>
 </ul>
 </div>

 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
 <h1>Welcome To .....</h1>
 </div>
```

i make teacher_choose_class as global variable the problem is that the value of this variable show in the alert message but when use this variable to get data by ajax no data return

Answer (score 0):

In the ajax part of your code, put an `alert(data);` on the return to see what you are getting back. Assuming you are getting back an array of JSON objects each with a property called child_name, try:

```
$("#teacher_classes").live("pageshow",function(event){
   alert(teacher_choose_class);
   $.post("teacher_login.php", { class_un:teacher_choose_class ,  get_students:"1"} , function(data ,status){
       alert(data);
       var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
       var  html = '';
       $.each(obj,function(i, item){
           var str =item.child_name;
           html +=  '<li><a href="#put_grade"><img src="student1.jpg">'+ str + '</a></li>';             
       });

       $("#student_list_class").append(html).listview("refresh");
    });                      
 });
```